# One-loop effective potentials and Schwinger's parametrisation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, potential, 1pi-effective-action

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108005) where they calculate the effective potential of a scalar field $\phi$, which is (without any justification)
$$
V_{eff} (\phi) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_I (-1)^{F_i} \int \dfrac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \log \left[ p^2 + M_I^2 (\phi) \right]. \tag{2.1}
$$
*Bonus question: Can someone indicate me where to find a justification for this?*

Now, in the next line, they say that using *Schwinger's parametrisation* we arrive to
$$
V_{eff} (\phi) = -\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_I (-1)^{F_i} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{dt}{t} \int \dfrac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \exp \left(-t\left[ p^2 + M_I^2 (\phi) \right]\right). \tag{2.2}
$$
Now, this makes no sense to me, I don't see at all how to go from (2.1) to (2.2). I tried to google Schwinger's parametrisation, but only found things about the Schwinger-Jordan angular momentum representation, which I think has nothing to do with this. I also found that the Schwinger trick is
$$
\dfrac{1}{A} = \int_0^\infty dt\, e^{-tA} ,
$$
but I don't see any relation between this and (2.2), apart from the fact that we may generate an integral with the correct limits. But this doesn't allow me to get rid of the logarithm.

Could someone please point me in the direction to find how to go from (2.1) to (2.2)? And what is Schwinger's parametrisation?

Comment: what happens if you integrate Schwinger's trick with respect to $A$?

Comment: That's a genius move! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Look for "Coleman-Weinberg potential". A text book derivation can be found e.g. in A. Zee, QFT in a Nutshell, p.240.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) to show that
$$
\ln \lambda-\ln \mu=  \int_0^\infty (e^{-\lambda t}- e^{-\mu t}) \frac{dt}{t}.
$$

Note that you need to have both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ under the same integral sign as
$$
  \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\frac{dt}{t}
- \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu t} \frac{dt}{t}
$$
is meaningless because  the separate  integrals are divergent at the lower limit.